# Increase size of fractions on multiple lines

Tags: amsmath, matrices, fractions

Inside a matrix, I have some very loaded (subscripts, greek letters, `\breve`) fractions:

```
\begin{equation}
Q_r = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_1}\bigg|_{t_1}     & \cdots & \frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_p}\bigg|_{t_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_1}\bigg|_{t_{N_{sp}}}     &\cdots & \frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_p}\bigg|_{t_{N_{sp}}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The fractions look to me too small compared to `\bigg|`. I tried `\medskip` but it was not effective.

**How can I increase their size and/or spacing to make them a better fit?**

p.s. I know they are not aligned, but readability comes before neatness.

Comment: Have you tried `\dfrac` and `\bigr|`?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi isn't `dfrac` for stacked fractions?

Comment: @writingthesis - "dfrac" is short for "display-style fraction". (The elements in a `bmatrix` enviroments are typeset in text-style math mode, not display-style math mode.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

- Use `\dfrac` ("display-style fraction") instead of `\frac` to increase the size of the fractional terms, and
- Keep using `\frac`, but reduce the size of the conditioning bars from `\bigg` to `\Big`.

Both methods are acceptable, typographically speaking. Which one is "better" will depend on many aspects of your documents (about which we know nothing).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "bmatrix" environment and "\dfrac" macro
\begin{document}

Method 1: Use \verb+\dfrac+ instead of \verb+\frac+
\[
Q_r = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_1}\bigg|_{t_1}     & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_p}\bigg|_{t_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\dfrac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_1}\bigg|_{t_{N_{\textit{sp}}}}     &\cdots & \dfrac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_p}\bigg|_{t_{N_{\textit{sp}}}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\bigskip
Method 2: Reduce the size of the vertical bars to \verb+\Big+
\[
Q_r = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_1}\Big|_{t_1}     & \cdots & \frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_p}\Big|_{t_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_1}\Big|_{t_{N_{\textit{sp}}}}     &\cdots & \frac{\partial \breve{y}_r}{\partial \theta_p}\Big|_{t_{N_{\textit{sp}}}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Mico and in order to show the `\right|` command:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\partderat}[3]{\left.\dfrac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}\right|_{\mathrlap{#3}\phantom{t_{N_{\textit{sp}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
Q_r = \begin{bmatrix}
\partderat{\breve{y}_r}{\theta_1}{t_1} & \cdots & \partderat{\breve{y}_r}{\theta_p}{t_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[\jot]
\partderat{\breve{y}_r}{\theta_1}{t_{N_{\textit{sp}}}}&\cdots & \partderat{\breve{y}_r}{\theta_p}{t_{N_{\textit{sp}}}}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

Note that it is very wise to use custom commands for this. Like this, you can switch between `\dfrac` and `\frac` later on. Or you can replace the automatic `\right|` by something fix when you have found your desired height.

[image]